# Non-equivalence $p$-norm on $\ell_p$, $L_p(X, \mu)$ to any inner product norm

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Show that the norm on the spaces $\ell_p$, $L_p(X, \mu)$ (where $(X, \mu)$ is a measure space containing infinitely many disjoint measurable sets of positive measure) is not equivalent to a norm generated by an inner product (unless $p = 2$).

I have trouble with this exercise. I don't know what to start from. In previous exercises I showed that the norm on the spaces $(\Bbb C^n, ∥ · ∥_p)$, $\ell_p$, $(C [a, b], ∥ · ∥_p)$, $L_p (X, \mu)$ is not generated by an inner product (unless $n = 1$, $p = 2$). I also generalized the inequality of the parallelogram on $n$ vectors. I think it's necessary. It is possible to construct many different inner products, but how to show non-equivalence?

Comment: Did you try polarization: $2\|{\textbf {u}}\|^{2}+2\|{\textbf {v}}\|^{2}=\|{\textbf {u}}+{\textbf {v}}\|^{2}+\|{\textbf {u}}-{\textbf {v}}\|^{2}$?

Comment: @Will M. Polarization I apply to prove that the $p$-norm is not generated by an inner product

Comment: I haven't read the answer below but completeness is preserved by equivalent norms, do the inner product norm would be complete and the space Hilber. Then you can use it is reflexive (but it is well-known the the dual of the $p$-space if the $p^*$-space where $p^*$ is conjugate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I realised that the only relevant part of my "proof" was the last one where I dismissively say that $L_q \not \simeq L_p$. This statement is actually proved in the same way as the original problem. I will leave my original post below (the use of duality was neat, I think, and, perhaps, one day I will be able to complete it in a satisfactory way) but, without further ado,

### Proof Number 1 (due to my friend)

Suppose $p < 2$, let $e_n$ be the standard basis in $l^p$ (the case of $L^p$ is similar), $(\cdot, \cdot)_H$ and $||\cdot||_H$ be the inner product and the corresponding norm on $l^p$. Since $||e_n||_p = 1$ and the norms are equivalent, there is $C > 0$ such that $||e_n||_H \le C$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By induction, choose $\epsilon_n \in \{-1, 1\}$ so that $$||\epsilon_1e_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_ne_n||_H \le C\sqrt{n}$$ (take $\epsilon_{n+1} = -\mathrm{sign}(\epsilon_1e_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_ne_n, e_{n+1})_H$). Then
$$\frac{||\epsilon_1e_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_ne_n||_H}{||\epsilon_1e_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_ne_n||_p} \le \frac{C\sqrt{n}}{n^{1/p}} \to 0$$
which is a contradiction. If $p>2$ do the same but take $\epsilon_{n+1} = \mathrm{sign}(\epsilon_1e_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_ne_n, e_{n+1})_H$ so that 
$$||\epsilon_1e_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_ne_n||_H \ge c\sqrt{n}.$$

### Proof Number 2 (outline)

Let $P_m$ be the standard projection on the first $m$ coordinates in $l^p$ and let $v_n$ be any orthonormal basis in $l^p$ as a Hilbert space. Choose $\epsilon > 0$. Since $P_m(v) \to v$ there is a function $M_\epsilon : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$\frac{||P_{M_\epsilon(n)}v_n||_p}{||v_n||_p} > 1 - \epsilon.$$ If for some $\epsilon$ the function $M_\epsilon$ is bounded, we can find a subsequence of $\{v_{n_k}\}$ that is almost the same in the first $\max M_\epsilon(n)$ coordinates, so $||\sum v_{n_k}||_p \sim k$ as $k \to \infty$. But $||\sum v_{n_k}||_H \sim \sqrt{k}$. That means $M_\epsilon(n)$ is unbounded for every $\epsilon$ and for every $d \in \mathbb{N}$ you can find $d$ vectors $\{v_{n_k}\}$ such that their norms in $l^p$ (up to $c\epsilon$) is concentrated in different coordinates. Then $||\sum v_{n_k}||_p \sim k^{1/p}$ but $||\sum v_{n_k}||_H \sim \sqrt{k}$.

---

Suppose there is an equivalent norm $||\cdot||_H$ generated by in inner product on $L_p$. By definition,
$$C_1||\cdot||_H \le ||\cdot||_p \le C_2||\cdot||_H.$$
The topologies they generate are the same so their dual spaces are the same (as sets). Moreover, for $f \in (L_p)^*$
$$||f||_{(L_p, ||\cdot||_p)^*} = \sup\limits_{x \in L_p} \frac{|f(x)|}{||x||_p}$$
so
$$\frac{||f||_{(L_p, ||\cdot||_H)^*}}{C_2} \le ||f||_{(L_p, ||\cdot||_p)^*} \le  \frac{||f||_{(L_p, ||\cdot||_H)^*}}{C_1}.$$
Therefore the norms induced on $(L_p)^*$ are equivalent as well. Thus, 
$$(L_q, ||\cdot||_q) \simeq (L_p, ||\cdot||_p)^* \simeq (L_p, ||\cdot||_H)^* \simeq (L_p, ||\cdot||_H) \simeq (L_p, ||\cdot||_p)$$
where "$\simeq$" means isomorphic as Banach spaces up to equivalent norms.  It remains to prove there is no isomorphism of this kind between $L_p$ and $L_q$.

Comment: Thank you! This is a beautiful solution, but we haven't yet passed dual space. I think that there should be another way to show this.

Comment: @Maxxx, I am afraid if you mark an answer as accepted, people aren't going to look at your question anymore. Regarding the problem: I told it to my friend and he suggested the following: every closed subspace in a Hilbert space is direct summand of it; so, you can try looking for a subspace in $l^p$ which isn't. Admittedly, that sounds pretty hard :(. I'll write you if we think of something.

Comment: @Maxxx, I changed my answer.

Comment: In the first proof choice of $\epsilon$ isn't a sufficient condition for the fact that $|| \epsilon_1 e_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_n e_n ||_H \geq C \sqrt{n}$. For example: let $\epsilon_1 = 1$ then $\epsilon_2 = sgn \left( e_1, e_1 \right) = 1$ but $|| e_1 + e_2 ||_H = \sqrt{|| e_1||^2_H + || e_2||^2_H + Re \left( e_1, e_2 \right) }$

Comment: Thus we need to $Re \left( e_1, e_2 \right)_H  \geq 0 $.

Comment: @Maxxx, the inner product was supposed to be with $e_{n+1}$, thanks. Edited. Basically, we choose $+$ or $-$ so that the angle will be at least $\pi/2$

Comment: I think that $ sgn \left( Re \left( \epsilon_1 e_1 + \ldots + \epsilon_n e_n , e_{n+1}  \right)_H \right) $. Thanks!